# How to bypass dpkg prompt?

Tags: dpkg

I'm creating a bash script to automate my post-install setup. To install opera I've got:

```
clear
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
echo --- Installing opera
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
## apt-transport-https is required
apt install -y apt-transport-https
curl http://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/pool/non-free/o/opera-stable/ \
| grep -o '64.deb">[^<]*' \
| sed 's/64.deb">/deb.opera.com\/opera-stable\/pool\/non-free\/o\/opera-stable\//' \
| xargs wget
chmod +x opera-stable*amd64.deb
dpkg -i opera-stable*amd64.deb
rm opera-stable*amd64.deb
```

The `curl` command downloads the 64 bit version of the opera `.deb` file.

When the `dpkg -i` command is run, an interactive ncurses-type screen appears asking whether to configure `/etc/apt/sources` (or what have you).

How do I avoid the 'question' screen (by pre-answer or accepting default) so that the script can be run unattended?

Comment: You could try `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg -i opera-stable*amd64.deb` for the installation.

Comment: Thanks! I'd already installed opera before posting the question. Before attempting your suggestion, I tried uninstalling with 'dpkg --remove opera' (got not-found/not-uninstalled error), then re-installed without the DEBIAN_FRONTEND bit to see if the interactive prompt (question) would appear again. It didn't. My answer to the question must be stored in a config file somewhere. So I can't test your suggestion at this time. I'll add it to my script anyway for my next install.

Comment: @Thomas Thanks. I tried your suggestion and it worked! No prompt when using this command: sudo DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg -i opera-stable*amd64.deb      If you make that an answer I can accept then I'll do so... if I figure out how (just started posting here).

Answer (score 2):

You could try `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` for the any dpkg operations to restrict the shell make any interactive displays for choices to make.

```
Eg: `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get upgrade`
```